# What is the best "Chat Now" component available for integration with my website?

Tags: instant-messaging, livechat

I'm looking for a "Chat Now" component to add to my website. I am using Drupal (running on a Windows server) if it matters.

I'm looking for something that the client initiates (I do not want to hound a client looking at my site). I want there to be no extra installs required for the client.

On my side, I want it to integrate with Skype or another common instant messaging tool.

I prefer free, but if it is low-cost (not a monthly fee) I would also be interested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like http://oggchat.com/ since it routes your chats to GTalk and GMail.